# How to refactor abstract method to DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, refactoring, abstract-methods

I have Asp.net Core project with default DI realization.
So I get BL-services instances, repositories, EF-context by DI.
I have abstract method that returns certain type by parameter.

```
IDocumentPreprocessor CreateDocumentPreprocessor(DocType docType)
    {
        switch (docType)
        {
            case DocType.Txt:
                return new TxtPreprocessor(_context, _docRepository);
            case DocType.Doc:
                return new DocPreprocessor(_docRepository);

            default:
                throw new ...
        }
    }
```

I don't like here direct creation of instance by "new".
But I'm not sure if it's possible to pass this logic to DI.
So the question - how to refactor it to DI usage?

Answer (score 3):

You wrap the logic in yet another DI-injectable service: an `IDocumentPreprocessorFactory`. There you inject factory methods for `IDocumentPreprocessor` implementations.

```
public interface IDocumentPreprocessorFactory
{
    IDocumentPreprocessor CreateDocumentPreprocessor(DocType docType);
}

public class DocumentPreprocessorFactory : IDocumentPreprocessorFactory
{
    private readonly Func<TxtPreprocessor> createTxtPreprocessor;

    private readonly Func<DocPreprocessor> createDocPreprocessor;

    public DocumentPreprocessorFactory(
        Func<TxtPreprocessor> createTxtPreprocessor,
        Func<DocPreprocessor> createDocPreprocessor)
    {
        this.createTxtPreprocessor = createTxtPreprocessor;
        this.createDocPreprocessor = createDocPreprocessor;
    }

    public IDocumentPreprocessor CreateDocumentPreprocessor(DocType docType)
    {
        switch (docType)
        {
            case DocType.Txt:
                return this.createTxtPreprocessor();
            case DocType.Doc:
                return this.createDocPreprocessor();
            default:
                throw new...
        }
    }
}
```

You must now extend your DI setup with the registrations of the factory methods. I have not used Core's DI yet, but I believe it might look something like this

```
services.AddSingleton<Func<DocPreprocessor>>(ctx => () => ctx.GetService<DocPreprocessor());
services.AddSingleton<Func<TxtPreprocessor>>(ctx => () => ctx.GetService<TxtPreprocessor());
```

Comment: At some point if OP wants a new `DocType`, such as `DocType.Pdf`, won't a change be required in the `DocumentPreprocessorFactory` class? While it is a reasonably simple change to add the new type, wouldn't it violate Open Closed principle to change the `DocumentPreprocessorFactory` class to include the new logic for adding Pdf functionality? Same if OP eventually wants `DocType.Xml`, etc?

Comment: @mike-maurer, you're absolutely right. But refactoring OP's `switch` block to be open-closed is a whole different story.

Comment: interesting. I'd be curious to see if there's an implementation that solves this without violating SOLID principles.

Answer (score 1):

this is can be help you..

```
        // object lifetime transient or others.. determine according to your needs
        services.AddTransient<TxtPreprocessor>();
        services.AddTransient<DocPreprocessor>();
        services.AddTransient(processorFactory =>
        {
            Func<DocType, IDocumentPreprocessor> factoryFunc = docType =>
            {
                switch (docType)
                {
                    case DocType.Txt:
                        return processorFactory.GetService<TxtPreprocessor>();
                    default:
                        return processorFactory.GetService<DocPreprocessor>();// DocPreprocessor is defult
                }
            };
            return factoryFunc;
        });
```

usage in any registered class..

```
public class AnyClass
{
    private readonly IDocumentPreprocessor _documentProcessor;

    public AnyClass(Func<DocType, IDocumentPreprocessor> factoryFunc)
    {
        _documentProcessor =  factoryFunc(DocType.Doc);
    }
}
```

you can encapsulate this function with factory class, if you want